# how to find out that the user is logged in

Tags: joomla

I need a module to be shown like this:

```
if (the user is logged in){
    \\ module should be this html(1)
}else{
    \\ module should be like this html(2)
}
```

is this possible?
should I add sth in the template index.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
if ($user->id){
    \\ module should be this html(1)
}else{
    \\ module should be like this html(2)
}
```